# A clickable button is not working for some css

Tags: html, css

I have some clickable link and it was working fine. But if I applied css for an another section those link. Here is the CSS:

```
.strong-view .wpmslider-wrapper {
  position: relative;


}
```

This css is only applicable for `.strong-view` class. But link of another section is not working. Here is the live link: http://www.cp3472.bmekuet.org/  Here 'Read More' button under Recent News is not working. If I just remove

```
.strong-view .wpmslider-wrapper {
  position: relative;

}
```

It works fine.

It is really strange!. What problem is going on? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's probably a `z-index` issue but the code you provided doesn't replicate the issue. https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/vmQbMm Please provide the minimal amount of code needed to reproduce it, otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: Thanks for your time.Please see the update.

Comment: Still isn't replicated https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VbVRYb **Please update your post with code that replicates the issue.** See here how to create a [mcve]

Comment: Updated again with live link. Is it okay now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have floated the 3 sections in the middle and didn't clear that float, and `.testimonial-container` *displays* below it, but is actually consuming all of the space where the 3 floated sections are because those floats aren't cleared.

The easiest fix is to add

```
.testmonial-container {
    clear: both;
}
```

A better fix would be to wrap the 3 floated sections in an element with a "clearfix" applied - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Answer (score 0):

Position relative may affect the `z-index` of an element (yes, I know that makes no sense, but that's how it seems to me, if anyone has any documentation behind that, I'd love to read it, this is just from my own experiences). Do you have anything else on the page with a z-index? If you change this class's z-index to something higher than your other z-indexes, it will probably solve the clicking problem.